# Environment Variables in Arduino IDE?

Tags: environment-variables, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

How to create and access the environment variables in Arduino IDE?

In my case, I want to connect the AWS IoT MQTT endpoint but am worried to save the certificate and private key in the file and in VCS (in that case I have to add the file in *.gitignore*)

Answer (score 0):

This accomplishes the goal I believe, but using a header file:

[Environment Variables for Arudino / ESP32 module code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64072448/environment-variables-for-arudino-esp32-module-code)

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64072580/11435898) indicates to create the file and not including into the repo. The question is different, I want my project to obtain the variables from bash, in that case, I'll run the project through the command.